# Where is tcp fast open in edge?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge

**Main question:**

When I first installed windows 10, there was a setting "tcp fast open" in the edge browser, and now it's gone, how can I enable it?

**Backstory:**

When I first tried edge, I thought it was a laggy piece of you know what, but after googling around, I bumped into a post where a person says that if you type "about:flags" into search bar in edge, and enable the "tcp fast open" feature, your browser will work faster. I did what that person said and it worked! Everything was loading super fast like in any other modern browser.

But after some update this feature is gone. One would assume that since it was an experimental feature, it's probably enabled by default already and isn't an experimental feature anymore, but according to my browsing experience, it's not the case and 60% of the time pages take 13 seconds to load (I counted it every time).

So, is there still a way to enable tcp fast open?

Optionally, could someone tell me what this feature does and how it works? I'm really curious to know!

Comment: TCP Fast Open is a well-known technique. Just search for it and you will find numerous resources for research. // It used to be an experimental feature back in 2016. It is most likely no longer experimental by now. You can always compare it with a different browser, like Firefox (enable `network.tcp.tcp_fastopen_enable`).

Comment: @DanielB do you know how to enable it in edge? It seems like it's disabled now, because edge is super slow.

Comment: It’s either on by default or removed. Simple as that. Keep in mind that it was only ever available on Insider Builds. If you have latency issues with your internet connection they may have gotten worse.

Comment: @DanielB everything works super fast in chrome, but not in edge on my end, so I don't think it's my internet connection issues. Too bad you can't enable it anymore...

Comment: Chrome doesn’t even support TCP Fast Open on Windows.

Comment: @DanielB oh, I guess edge sucks then, lol.

Comment: @DanielB where do I need to type network.tcp.tcp_fastopen_enable to enable this feature in firefox?

Comment: About page, same as any configuration option enabled, manually

Comment: EdgeHTML 16 doesn’t support TFO, due to complaints, Microsoft disabled it after previously enabling it in EdgeHTML on 15.  What you want (Enabling TFO on the current version of Edge) isn’t possible

Comment: Also, comments in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635080 make for an interesting read

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Windows 10, in Edge type about:flags in the address bar, then press ctrl-shift-d. This will give you additional settings on the about:flags screen and at the bottom (scroll-down!) you will see "Enable TCP Fast Open"

Comment: Hey Jeff, welcome to Superuser! Did you read the question in full? The user mentions that they've already tried this and that the feature seems to now be gone. Consider editing your question to respond to this user's specific needs

Comment: I read the question in the full. The user did not see the TCP Fast Open option as they did not press ctrl-shift-d on about:flags. Once you press ctrl-shift-d it reveals additional options that include the TCP Fast Open.

Comment: I think that's the old Edge, as CTRL-Shift-D now tries to add the current page to favorites in Chromium Edge